# Debugger step in /step out options

Tags: c++, debugging

Short intro story:
So I am  a freshman at a IT college I have a very important and hard time intensive exam in form of c++ code in visual studio2015. Basically you are given 90 mins to finish a bug riddled code given to you by the professor.You are given just function names and  a few conditions that need to be there.The problem is that you have only 90 mins to do as much as you can.The code doesn't need to be 100% complete but it musnt have breaks or runtime errors.So the only way is to use step in and step out¸very very slowly.
The step into/ step out debugging goes into a lot of headers and is time consuming ,you cant just bash f11 because then you might miss the code you are suspicios.So..

Is there a way to set the step into NOT to display code that is found inside headers and only show you your code ?

Comment: It would be better for you to *read* the code and spot the errors prior to using a debugger to step into/out of code that works fine

Comment: You do know there is also `F10` to "step over" so you don't have to `F11` step in/out of every single function call...

Comment: RTFM [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), with a particular focus [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx#Anchor_2) :)

Comment: I suspect (i.e. hope) that you're given not enough time for repeatedly single-stepping through the program, but that there's plenty of time for bug-fixing by reading and thinking if you have a solid enough understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tools menu ->options->debugging

from MS help:-

"Enable Just My Code

The debugger displays and steps into user code ("My Code") only, ignoring system code and other code that is optimized or that does not have debugging symbols."

Comment: No problem, if it answered your question you can thank me by marking it as the accepted answer.